# Failure 2673 The source parcel length does not match data that was defined

Tags: import, teradata, bteq

Hi I am trying to import data into one of the tables using BTEQ import.i am  using the following script to load data to flat file
I am exporting a file from oracle and importing them into Teradata table.
The table structure of my TERADAT table is as follows:

```
create multiset table TableName  ,NO FALLBACK ,
      NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     MAP = TD_MAP2
     (
     Frst_Name VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL,
     Status_Code CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     UPDATE_DT DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' NOT NULL
     );
```

And this is the bteq import i am using:

```
bteq <<EOF
.LOGON <Teardata_server>/<username>,<password>;
.PACK 1000
.IMPORT VARTEXT ',' FILE=$FILE_NM1
.REPEAT *
USING(Frst_Name VARCHAR(50),Status_Code VARCHAR(50))
insert into WORK_MCID_STREQUI_VAL_LKUP (Frst_Name,Status_Code,UPDATE_DT)
values ( :Frst_Name,:STR_VAL2,:Status_Code,CURRENT_DATE);

.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
```

I am getting an error as  :
*** Warning: Out of data.
*** Failure 2673 The source parcel length does not match data that was defined.

All the data in the exported file is matching the length as well infact lesser than the one used in using clause.
Please help me with this.

I tried various options like trying to use various possibilities like casting the date and but nothing seems to work

Comment: Your status_code column in your DDL is char(5), in your import statement it's varchar(50).

Comment: Your INSERT has 3 column names but 4 values.